# No resource found that matches the given name after upgrading to appcompat v24

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm getting this error on `app:toolbarId` when defining a collapsing toolbar on Android. As you can see below, toolbar is defined. I noticed I can work around it by omitting the id of the toolbar altogether (it then takes the first toolbar it encounters) but I cannot figure out why it stopped working and if there's anything I'm missing... Any idea?

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
        ... >

        <ImageView
            ... />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            ... />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the issue was a forward reference. Not a v23/v24 issue but a result of some other change I made in parallel... Originally this layout XML wasn't the first on the (alphabetical) list of layout XMLs so there was a previous layout XML (of some other activity) defining a `@id/toolbar`. That was enough for gradle to accept the `app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"` in this activity as a valid reference. Luckily (or not...) in run time it still referred to the correct toolbar - the `@id/toolbar` of this activity - so I didn't notice my (forward reference) mistake.

The fix was simple - move the "+" to the (first) reference in `app;toolbarId` (which is what I should have done in the first place anyway). See below:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        ... >

        <ImageView
            ... />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
            android:id="@id/toolbar"
            ... />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: you're right, I was surprised as well so - after your comment - I decided to double check... realized the root cause wasn't v24 but some other change... will update my answer accordingly.